# Create exceptions in test classes for a process builder?

Tags: apex, unit-test, process-builder, exception

Is is possible to create exceptions in a Test Class for (example) **Process Builder "XYZ NAME"**? *To avoid the test class running that process.*

Right now my work-around is to manipulate the criteria in either the Process Builder or in the Test Class so that it doesn't trigger the Process builder.

Comment: I think what you have currently is the correct approach. This way you are in turn also testing your PB's behavior and that you can validate the results accordingly. Skipping a particular flow could lead to potential failures when you move from org to org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't prevent code or automation from running in a unit test context other than by manipulating your test data and/or entry criteria.

You can do this in more or less sophisticated ways, however. For example, you can use a Custom Setting of Hierarchy type to gate your Process by referring to it in one of your criteria. Since Custom Settings are data, they're not visible in your unit test context unless your unit test proactively creates them. That's a perfectly fine way to inhibit a trigger or process or workflow rule selectively both in production use (e.g., for an integration user) or in a test context.

Consider however whether by doing so you may be damaging the efficacy or validity of your test results. If in production your code will be running with the process active, you'll want to validate its behavior in that environment.

Comment: The "sophisticated" way would be to use UnitOfWork and ApexMocks so no DML actually executes and hence no WFR or PB fires. This would be useful for unit testing but as you point out, avoiding the PB execution could lead to errors in PROD

Answer (score 0):

Best is to create your test data in such a way that it doesn't pass the process criteria. If you still need to do it, you can use hierarchy type custom setting with some boolean field to skip the process builder. Refer this link to understand how to use hierarchy type custom setting in process builder: https://jenwlee.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/use-custom-settings-in-process-builder/

You may also want to check if Custom Metadata are allowed in process yet or not because it was planned to be released in Winter 19 release. Check out this idea as it says delivered: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E32UQAS